# How do I insert data manually into the pivot table? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have an application that contains 2 models: User and Event
There's a many to many relationship between them and I am using a pivot table (called participants). I need to insert the data into the pivot (participants) table manually (specify each column's value).
I can't use the relationship insert, because I am leaving the user_id column blank. (Therefore it won't be a "relationshipped" column.) Any ideas how to make this scenario real, please?

Comment: why are you leaving user_id column blank ? nevertheless, use DB::table('pivot_table')->insert(['column' => 'value']);

Comment: Because I want to allow the operation to the guests as well. Will try, thanks!

Comment: A pivot table, i.e. a table that links 2 tables via their ids, should not allow one of them to be blank... You can use the syntax noted above, but if implemented properly, your database shouldn't allow that, as both columns should be `NOT NULL`

Comment: Works. Didn't know I can use DB class with eloquent. Thank you!